# Gerar um novo controle para cada item listado

Tags: c#, wpf

Olá, com base no código abaixo, gostaria de saber como gerar um novo controle( no meu caso um grid) para cada item existente na minha ListBox...

Minha ListBox:

```
<ListBox Height="380.585" Width="258.998">
   <ListBoxItem x:Name="i" Content="grade"/>
   <ListBoxItem x:Name="ii" Content="grade"/>
   <ListBoxItem x:Name="iii" Content="grade"/>
   <ListBoxItem x:Name="iv" Content="grade"/>
   <ListBoxItem x:Name="v" Content="grade"/>
</ListBox>
```

**Explicação:**
 A razão da função é que eu desejo usar um *WrapPannel* para Exibir modelos gráficos referentes a cada item, e sendo assim... sempre existir o número de *Grids* correspondentes aos items na lista.

Comment: Thiago, no load você chama um método que cria um novo controle, para cada item. Você poderia usar foreach e criar um novo controle dinamicamente.
Acredito que esse link te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275502/how-to-dynamically-add-gridviews-side-by-side-using-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: Obrigado cara, eu consegui com sua ajuda também, tenta postar como resposta com mais detalhes para ajudar outros também e até melhorar o que aprendi, eu marco como resposta por que seu comentário já contem uma resposta.